# Is there an objectbox data browser for a flutter project?

Tags: dart, objectbox

Is there an objectbox data browser for a flutter project?

Or can I use https://docs.objectbox.io/data-browser somehow?

Answer (score 1):

No there's currently not. You can upvote this to bring it to dart: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues/148

You could use the data browser from objectbox-java but probably only by moving the database to an objectbox-java project.